# Microchip studio disable wrap (code folding) on multi line comments

Tags: embedded, atmelstudio

In microchip studio, when I have multi-line comments inside a function, the code wrap does not work well, as it suggests wrapping only the comments:

[image: multi line comments microchip]

But if I remove the multi-line comments, it will suggest to wrap the function as normal:

[image: microchip studio wrap code]

How can I always have the function wrap enabled, even when I have multi-line comments inside the function?

Comment: (Having used a lot of IDEs, but no current version of Microchip Studio...) Is it possible, that the folding marker depends on the text cursor or mouse pointer position?

Comment: @thebusybee It is always the same, no correlation with cursor position.

Comment: That is not "_wrapping_"; that is "_code folding_".  A question I would suggest for the product's technical or community support.

Comment: @Clifford I edited the title. Thank you, I will send a message to the product's community support.